# catkin is compiling c++ with python

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm a newbie in ROS, and after making the tutorials I'm trying to rosificate a C++ project that already is running in my BeagleBone Black.

My problem is that, when I compile the code using `catkin_make_isolated` , my main.cpp is not being properly built up:in the compilation process, `python`is being used, instead of `gcc` compiler. This means that I cannot execute the node using `rosrun <package> main` even if I have done `source devel/setup.bash` witihin `catkin_ws`.

This is the print out of the command line in the compilation process:

```
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
```

And this is how the CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ros_erle_ubled)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ros_erle_ubled
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
)

 include_directories(include)
 include_directories(
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(main src/GPIO_BBB.cpp src/DycoLEDDriver.cpp src/DycoLED_Linux.cpp src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(main ros_erle_ubled_main_cpp)
```

I have also tried to force to use `gcc compiler` executing the next command (with little success):

`catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc  --pkg ros_ubled`

Any idea how can I proceed??

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: console output of running `catkin_make_isolated`:

```
root@beaglebone:~/ros_catkin_ws#  catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.7  --pkg ros_ubled
Base path: /root/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /root/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated
Devel space: /root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated
Install space: /root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
Additional CMake Arguments: -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.7
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~  traversing 48 packages in topological order:
~~  - catkin
~~  - genmsg
~~  - gencpp
~~  - genlisp
~~  - genpy
~~  - console_bridge (plain cmake)
~~  - cpp_common
~~  - message_generation
~~  - message_runtime
~~  - mk
~~  - ros
~~  - ros_comm
~~  - rosbash
~~  - rosboost_cfg
~~  - rosbuild
~~  - rosclean
~~  - roscpp_traits
~~  - roscreate
~~  - rosgraph
~~  - roslang
~~  - rosmake
~~  - rosmaster
~~  - rosmsg
~~  - rospack
~~  - roslib
~~  - rosparam
~~  - rospy
~~  - rosservice
~~  - rostime
~~  - roscpp_serialization
~~  - rosbag_storage
~~  - roslaunch
~~  - rosunit
~~  - rosconsole
~~  - rostest
~~  - std_msgs
~~  - rosgraph_msgs
~~  - std_srvs
~~  - xmlrpcpp
~~  - roscpp
~~  - ros_ubled
~~  - rosout
~~  - message_filters
~~  - rosnode
~~  - rostopic
~~  - roswtf
~~  - topic_tools
~~  - rosbag
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Skipping package: 'catkin'
Skipping package: 'genmsg'
Skipping package: 'gencpp'
Skipping package: 'genlisp'
Skipping package: 'genpy'
Skipping package: 'console_bridge'
Skipping package: 'cpp_common'
Skipping package: 'message_generation'
Skipping package: 'message_runtime'
Skipping package: 'mk'
Skipping package: 'ros'
Skipping package: 'ros_comm'
Skipping package: 'rosbash'
Skipping package: 'rosboost_cfg'
Skipping package: 'rosbuild'
Skipping package: 'rosclean'
Skipping package: 'roscpp_traits'
Skipping package: 'roscreate'
Skipping package: 'rosgraph'
Skipping package: 'roslang'
Skipping package: 'rosmake'
Skipping package: 'rosmaster'
Skipping package: 'rosmsg'
Skipping package: 'rospack'
Skipping package: 'roslib'
Skipping package: 'rosparam'
Skipping package: 'rospy'
Skipping package: 'rosservice'
Skipping package: 'rostime'
Skipping package: 'roscpp_serialization'
Skipping package: 'rosbag_storage'
Skipping package: 'roslaunch'
Skipping package: 'rosunit'
Skipping package: 'rosconsole'
Skipping package: 'rostest'
Skipping package: 'std_msgs'
Skipping package: 'rosgraph_msgs'
Skipping package: 'std_srvs'
Skipping package: 'xmlrpcpp'
Skipping package: 'roscpp'

==> Processing catkin package: 'ros_ubled'
==> Building with env: '/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ros_ubled'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ros_ubled/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/xmlrpcpp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_srvs;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosgraph_msgs;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rostest;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosconsole;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosunit;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslaunch;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosbag_storage;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp_serialization;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rostime;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosservice;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospy;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosparam;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslib;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosmsg;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosmaster;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosmake;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslang;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosgraph;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscreate;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp_traits;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosclean;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosbuild;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosboost_cfg;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosbash;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/ros_comm;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/ros;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/mk;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/message_runtime;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/message_generation;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cpp_common;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/console_bridge;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genpy;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genlisp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/gencpp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genmsg;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin;/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/xmlrpcpp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_srvs;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosgraph_msgs;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rostest;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosconsole;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosunit;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslaunch;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosbag_storage;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp_serialization;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rostime;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosservice;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospy;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosparam;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslib;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosmsg;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosmaster;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosmake;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslang;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosgraph;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscreate;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roscpp_traits;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosclean;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosbuild;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosboost_cfg;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosbash;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/ros_comm;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/ros;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/mk;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/message_runtime;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/message_generation;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cpp_common;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genpy;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genlisp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/gencpp;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genmsg;/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin;/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ros_ubled/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.89
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ros_ubled
==> make -j1 -l1 in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ros_ubled'
Linking CXX executable devel/lib/ros_ubled/main
[100%] Built target main
<== Finished processing package [41 of 48]: 'ros_ubled'
Skipping package: 'rosout'
Skipping package: 'message_filters'
Skipping package: 'rosnode'
Skipping package: 'rostopic'
Skipping package: 'roswtf'
Skipping package: 'topic_tools'
Skipping package: 'rosbag'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202216/catkin-is-compiling-c++-with-python/) by [imuguruza](https://answers.ros.org/users/21548/imuguruza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-02**:
I'm pretty sure it is not using python as a c++ compiler. The message just means that this is the python executable path being used for python. Please post the full catkin_make output.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-02**:
I was just going to post the same @dornhege: that message just tells you which version of Python `catkin` has found. It does not mean that your c++ is being 'compiled' by python.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-02**:\

> add_dependencies(main ros_erle_ubled_main_cpp)

@imuguraza: could you tell us what this line is for?

**Comment by [imuguruza](https://answers.ros.org/users/21548/imuguruza/) on 2015-02-02**:
Here the commandline output:
http://pastebin.com/VpggzZjT

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-02**:
According to that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to:

```
==> make -j1 -l1 in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/ros_ubled'
Linking CXX executable devel/lib/ros_ubled/main
[100%] Built target main
<== Finished processing package [41 of 48]: 'ros_ubled'
```

your C++ target has been built. Could you check the contents of `/root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/lib/ros_ubled`? If I'm not mistaked, there should be a binary called `main` in there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imuguruza](https://answers.ros.org/users/21548/imuguruza/) on 2015-02-02**:
Yes, the main.elf is there! Thanks, but why is not appearing when I type `rosrun ros_ubled`  and press `tab` key??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-02**:
After you've ran `catkin_make_isolated`, source `devel/setup.bash` in a new terminal. If `rosrun` can't find your binary, try a `rospack profile` in the same terminal. If it still can't find it, something is not right. Btw, why is it `main.elf`? Are you cross-compiling?